# Java regexp оставить цифры и плюс

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Не силен в регулярных выражениях. Нужно чтобы строка +7 (987) 654-32-10 была приведена к виду +79876543210.

```
String number = number.replaceAll("regex", "");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все получилось довольно просто

1. Нужно чтобы был указан диапазон того, что я хочу оставить.

   `"[0-9\\+]"`
2. Нужно сделать отрицание

   `String number = number.replaceAll("[^0-9\\+]", "");`

Больше всего времени потратил на отрицание.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю `+` нужно оставлять только если он вначале. Конечно врядли кто-то запишет номер в стиле `+7 (987) 654+32+10`. На случай если такой вариант возможен можно сделать такой вариант

```
String number = number.replaceAll("^[^0-9\\+]|(?<=.)[^0-9]+", "");
```